# Rollup with GroupBy using QueryDSL and PostgreSQL database

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jpa, querydsl

I am using QueryDSL to form queries in Java8. Database is PostgreSQL.

For one of the features I need to use the ROLLUP functionality with GroupBy in PostgreSQL but I am unable to do the same using QueryDSL methods. I am also very new to QueryDSL.

Presently, this is how my query builder code looks like.

```java
JPAQuery query = repository.getQueryDSL().createQuery(QEntity.entity).where(finalPredicate)
                .groupBy(groupByFields.toArray(new Expression[0]))
                .orderBy(orderSpecifierArray)
                .limit(pageSize);
```

// to fetch the results

```java
query.select(alarmProjectionFactory).fetch()
```

I want to include ROLLUP with the above .groupBy method.

In the final query I want something like this:

```sql
GROUP BY Rollup(field1, field2)
```

instead of:

```sql
GROUP BY field1, field2.
```

Please suggest if its possible to do in code using QueryDSL and the changes required.

Comment: Even if QueryDSL can do it, I doubt JPA will be able to handle that

Comment: I am fine with not using JPAQuery. It there a way around?